# Git push without creating new branch

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-remote, pull-request

I have 2 remote branches `remote/master` and `remote/feature`, and a local branch `foo` that was set up to track `remote/feature`.

```
[git: foo] $ git branch -u remote/feature
```

I want to push my commits to `feature` and issue a PR against `master`.

When I push my commits to remote, a new remote branch named `foo` is created automatically (which I don't want to).

```
$ git push remote foo 
  * [new branch]     foo -> foo

$ git remote show remote
Local refs configured for 'git push':
    feature pushes to feature (up to date)
    foo     pushes to foo     (up to date)
    master  pushes to master  (up to date)
```

In attempt to not creating new branch, I try this:

```
$ git push remote foo:feature
sha-1...sha-2 foo -> feature
```

This time, new branch is not created but the exiting PR is updated with my commits, which is also not what I want.

How can I push to remote and create a new PR without creating a new branch or updating existing PR?

Comment: Please provide more information about the existing PR that is getting updated.

Comment: @NickZavaritsky, the PR was created by another person. When I `git push remote foo:feature`, my commits are appended to the list of its commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is already an active pull request from your remote `feature` branch to `master`, pushing new commits to `feature` will update the existing pull request.

This is by design; GitHub [encourages discussion and modification of pull requests before they are merged](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/):

> You can also continue to push to your branch in light of discussion and feedback about your commits. If someone comments that you forgot to do something or if there is a bug in the code, you can fix it in your branch and push up the change. GitHub will show your new commits and any additional feedback you may receive in the unified Pull Request view.

The only way to submit a new pull request is to do it from a different branch.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. Sorry that I was not clear but the existing PR was created by another person, so I expect my push to create another PR instead of updating the existing one. Also, when you push remote, `git push remote your-local-branch`, a PR is created without creating new remote branch, correct? Normally, you will see several PRs exist while there is only 1 branch master, right?

Comment: @chepukha, whether another person created the first PR isn't relevant. GitHub pull requests are designed as a collaborative feature; many people might contribute to them before they're merged.

Comment: @chepukha, pull requests can be between any two branches, not just `master` and some other branch. Many projects will have several active PRs against `master`. Others will have PRs against other branches (and in fact some projects don't have a `master` branch at all). The way pull requests are used in your project is up to whoever makes contribution guidelines for the project.

Comment: I understand that PR can be btw any 2 branches. What I'm not clear is why I can't submit a PR without creating a new remote branch. In my case, I've created a different branch, `foo`, and push remote from there. I want to issue a PR but I don't want to have a `remote/foo` branch. Does it make sense?

Comment: @chepukha, it makes sense but I don't think it's possible. A GitHub PR requests that one branch be merged into another. Adding commits to a branch where a PR already exists simply adds commits to that existing PR. The only way to submit a new PR is to do it from a separate branch.